# Vuejs initialization Typerror

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a new vue application but I keep getting this Type Error, I'll show you my entire command line. All I did was run `npm init vue@latest`

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Vue.js - The Progressive JavaScript Framework

TypeError: (0 , import_node_util.parseArgs) is not a function
    at init (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2f7e7bff16d1c534\node_modules\create-vue\outfile.cjs:4481:72)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2f7e7bff16d1c534\node_modules\create-vue\outfile.cjs:4862:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I could not find a solution anywhere

my node version is v16.16.0

Comment: Try creating a new project with `npx create-vue <project-name>`

Comment: It's likely wrong version of Node.  Tell us result of `node -v` in your command line.  According to the Vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start#creating-a-vue-application), Node 18.3 or higher is a prerequisite.

Comment: I'm using v16.16.0

Comment: i just used npx create-vue and it gave me the same exact error!

Comment: i upgraded my node version to 18.17.0 and it worked! thank you